# how to sort and move elements inside a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

`el` should be movable:
`up` and `down` - inside the parent - so columns should be sortable
and `left-right` - from one column to another
Any help

```js
$("#cola, #colb, #colc, #cold").sortable({
    containment: "parent"
});

$("#cola, #colb, #colc, #cold").droppable();

$('.el').draggable({

});
```

```css
.grid{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
width:50%;
}
.col{
height:100vh;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
.el{
line-height:25px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
margin:14px 0;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='grid'>
<div class='col' id='cola'>
<div class='el'>A</div>
<div class='el'>A</div>
<div class='el'>A</div>
</div>
<div class='col' id='colb'>
<div class='el'>B</div>
<div class='el'>B</div>
<div class='el'>B</div>
</div>
<div class='col' id='colc'>
<div class='el'>C</div>
<div class='el'>C</div>
<div class='el'>C</div>
</div>
<div class='col' id='cold'>
<div class='el'>D</div>
<div class='el'>D</div>
<div class='el'>D</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing overflow-y? Won't that do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating it. Here is a basic sortable, you will want to use `items` and `connectWith` options.

```js
$(".col").sortable({
  containment: ".grid",
  items: "> div.el",
  connectWith: ".col"
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 50%;
}

.col {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.el {
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 14px 0;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col' id='cola'>
    <div class='el'>A-1</div>
    <div class='el'>A-2</div>
    <div class='el'>A-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col' id='colb'>
    <div class='el'>B-1</div>
    <div class='el'>B-2</div>
    <div class='el'>B-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col' id='colc'>
    <div class='el'>C-1</div>
    <div class='el'>C-2</div>
    <div class='el'>C-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col' id='cold'>
    <div class='el'>D-1</div>
    <div class='el'>D-2</div>
    <div class='el'>D-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```